# Laravel where id must contain [1,2,3]

Tags: laravel

I want to get all the user details where id = 1 and id = 2 and id = 3.

I don't want something like
`->whereIn('id',[1,2,3])`

Because it returns where id = 1 or id = 2 or id = 3.

`[1,2,3]` is an array of ids.

Comment: I don't quit follow, do you want the tree users or just one ?

Comment: whats the wring with ```whereIn```

Answer (score 1):

While it is not clear what are you trying to accomplish, you could do the following in case when you need more than one conditional to be true:

```
UserDetails::where(function ($userDetail) {
    return $userDetail->where([
        ['id', 1],
        ['id', 2],
        ['id', 3]
    ]);
});
```